# Python Can't Access Windows 7 User Folder

Tags: python, windows, permissions

I have a wxPython app that writes user data to the Users folder at close. In most cases it works fine. However, I get some error reports from users that the app cannot write to the Users/username folder.

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u\'C:\\Users\\usersname\\AppData\\Roaming\\app\\data.dat\'

What situation can cause a user not to be able to write to their own user folder? Does the user not always have read/write permissions to their own Users/username folder? How can I compensate for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason is that the file is locked. In this case you have no permission to write to the file until it is released.
Are you sure you don't lock the file somehow yourself?!

Comment: No, I don't see how. The app works fine on most systems. It is just a few that have this error. Even if there are two instances of the app running and one is closed, I cannot reproduce this error.